# How to convert String tokens into CoreLabel instances (StanfordNLP)?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, text-mining

Can we convert a String token into a [CoreLabel](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/CoreLabel.html) instance?

So far, I am using:

```
CoreLabelTokenFactory c = new CoreLabelTokenFactory();  
CoreLabel tokens = c.makeToken("going",0,"going".length());
```

The string gets converted, however with this approach, `CoreLabel` is not working in finding lemma's and pos.

Comment: What would the use case be of making CoreLabels?  I would imagine that the lemma and pos are not there because they probably did not go through the pipeline and thus you would have to supply them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code to demonstrate going from a raw String to an Annotation object:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

public class TokenizeExample {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        String text = "Here is a sentence.  Here is another sentence.";
        Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        pipeline.annotate(document);
        for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
            for (CoreLabel cl : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
                System.out.println("---");
                System.out.println(cl);
                System.out.println(cl.get(CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class));
                System.out.println(cl.get(CoreAnnotations.LemmaAnnotation.class));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you get Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.2 from here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml